# "C нами победа точно ваша"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Помогите правильно написать!

Comment: спасибо!!!

Answer (score 1):

В предложении желательно поставить тире, но место его расположения зависит от контекста, который уточняет смысл сообщения и определяет постановку логического ударения.

Если нужно выделить "нас, нашу заслугу", то пишем: С НАМИ - победа точно ваша. Если речь идет о возможности победы (при нашем участии), то лучше использовать такой вариант: С нами ПОБЕДА - точно ваша.

Comment: Для окончательного ответа надо знать текст, из которого изъято предложение. Наличие или отсутствие тире одинаково возможно. Если именное сказуемое  выражено местоимением, то в базовом варианте тире не ставится.  Но без авторского тире предложение совершенно невыразительно, если только такая невыразительность не входит в художественную задачу автора.

Answer (score 1):

Структура предложения не требует знаков препинания. Разве что точки в конце и прописной буквы в начале. Но интонационное тире возможно, хотя и необязательно.